# USB 3.0 VS MIPI CSI-2 camera interface on Embedded Linux system. Which one is better from both hardware and software perspective?

Tags: usb, embedded, camera, linux, csi

I have a Sony FCB series [camera](https://www.image-sensing-solutions.eu/FCB-EV7520.html) (1920x1080) and looking for a better interface protocol to connect it with processors like NXP, TI or any similar embedded processor.

The camera has a LVDS out port but I have seen that no processor has LVDS input, so we need some converter to connect it with processor available on the market?

Now I'm confused between MIPI CSI-2 and USB 3.0 interface.

1. Which one faster? from both hardware and software (Linux operating system) perspective.
2. CPU overhead difference?

Here the camera is not finalized one and I can choose the camera which can give direct CSI-2 or USB 3.0 so I don't have to look for the converter.

Answer (score 1):

CPU overhead depends mainly on how much processing the CPU can offload to other peripherals. A USB link requires the CPU to tell the USB controller to transfer data, a MIPI link requires the CPU to tell the MIPI controller to transfer data.

Neither protocol can be implemented without dedicated logic.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/VPU-performance-CSI-2-MIPI-camera-vs-USB-camera/m-p/293745), on an NXP iMX6 MCU, a MPI CSI interface camera uses approximately 8-15% of the MCU, whereas a USB3 interface camera uses approximately 50% of the MCU (YMMV).

Comment: Because links routinely go dead, please add some more description of the linked site (citing the source), the subject and author.  Direct quotes of relevant sections may be worthwhile as well.  Try to give this answer a long lifetime by making it less dependent on a single blind link.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen And indeed, link is now dead.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Hi, FYI I've just updated the link to the current, working link on their updated forum.